# Display fractions in a ComboBox option list

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform, fractions

I create an option list to choose 1/4, 1/2 or 3/4 from a ComboBox on a userform.

The data comes from Sheet1 that shows the correct format for each value.

Example

| Column A |
| --- |
| 1/4 |
| 1/2 |
| 3/4 |

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.List = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A3").Value
End Sub
```

When I run the form the ComboBox shows 0.25, 0.5 or 0.75.

I need to show in fraction format.

Answer (score 2):

Creating an array and setting the array seems to work for the `.text` field representation, for a combobox:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Sheets(1)
        Dim textArray As Variant
        ReDim textArray(.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(3, 1)).Count - 1)
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(textArray) To UBound(textArray)
            textArray(i) = .Cells(i + 1, 1).Text
        Next i
    End With
    ComboBox1.List = textArray
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Alternative:

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        ComboBox1.List = .Evaluate("TEXT(A1:A3,""# ?/?"")")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'll be the first to admit it:  I have no idea how you got to that, but that is quite nice.  This displays all values as fractions, though I did just notice my "0.3" turned into "2/7" when displayed.  Regardless, this is pretty snazzy if you're starting with only fractions!

Comment: @Cyril - I think as you noted it has the downside that you're not allowed to mix number formats in the output...

Answer (score 0):

Both answers applied for my situation.
Since I'm not performing any numerical operation with those fractions, Tim's option is quick and easy.
For mathematical operations, the option from Cyril is the answer.

An option I figured out is quicker, easier and better for my particular situation, because I'm not using the fraction for a numerical operation, was to use the backward slash symbol. Excel takes the characters as text and doesn't change anything.